# How to handle columns with brackets and spaces

Tags: csvsimple

I am exporting csv to pdf format as below and in one of the column i have spaces between words and brackets for some of the rows and also the texts are 26 characters long as below and I guess because of this, the pdf doesnot generate. could anyone suggest me if there is a way to handle such cases.

```
The world is bigger enough
wide columns (usecase)
```

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{9cm}|p{4cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{\textsf{column1}} & \textbf{\textsf{column2}} & \textbf{\textsf{column3}} \\\hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \textbf{\textsf{column1}} & \textbf{\textsf{column2}} & \textbf{\textsf{column3}}  \\\hline
    \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
    \csvreader[
                separator=semicolon,
                column count=3,
                check column count,
                respect all=true,
                before reading={\catcode`\_=11},
                after reading={\catcode`\_=8},
                late after line=\\\hline
    ]{longtable.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no problem with brackets, it was blackshash problem. fixed it